# React Ionic Navigation with directly passed functional props

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router

How do I push a page using React and Ionic with functional props?

I did try:

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/edit_some_property',
  state: {
    onSetSomeProperty(val) { setSomeState(val) }
  }
})
```

But that throws:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': onSetSomeProperty(val) { setSomeState(val); } could not be cloned.

Apparently, `state` is serialized to a string, so passing functions isn't going to work.

Or is there another approach that would work better for pushing screens with callbacks to the previous screen?

---

**Background and Detail:**

I have a very hierarchical style React + Ionic app.

1. Choose an item from a list, push a screen with item details.
2. Choose a sub item from a list, push a screen with sub item details.
3. Tap to edit an attribute, push a screen with form fields, and callback to the previous screen with the result.

Now it appears that in order to navigate from screen to screen, Ionic requires you to use React Router, where each page has a unique URL. But this doesn't work so well here since each screen depends on the state of previous screens.

This means that there is no apparent way to communicate rich props between pages. If I have a callback to the previous page, I can't pass that along because I don't have direct access to component being pushed with the router in the way.

---

There's also `ion-nav` https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav which is closer to what I think I need, but that doesn't seem to have a react interface at all.

I tried:

```
<IonNav root={Home} />
```

Which throws this, deep in obfuscated internals:

> Error: framework delegate is missing

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was way off base sorry. I did some testing, and found that anything passed to state needs to be serializable. In order to do this for a function, others have reported that https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-json-stringify helped them out.